# pygame-How to replace an image with an other one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this sort of code:

```
width = 100
height = 50
gameDisplay.blit(button, (width, height))
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            # replace the button's image with another
```

Is there any function or something that would let me replace the image with another?

Comment: Use a global `image` then reset the value as needed while blitting continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'replace' anything you've drawn. What you do is that you draw new images over the existing ones. Usually, you clear the screen and redraw your images every loop. Here's pseudo-code illustrating what a typical game loop looks like. I'll use *screen* as variable name instead of *gameDisplay*, because *gameDisplay* goes against PEP-8 naming convention.

```
while True:
    handle_time()  # Make sure your programs run at constant FPS.
    handle_events()  # Handle user interactions.
    handle_game_logic()  # Use the time and interactions to update game objects and such.

    screen.fill(background_color)  # Clear the screen / Fill the screen with a background color.
    screen.blit(image, rect)  # Blit an image on some destination.  Usually you blit more than one image using pygame.sprite.Group.
    pygame.display.update()  # Or 'pygame.display.flip()'.
```

For your code you probably should do something like this:

```
rect = pygame.Rect((x_position, y_position), (button_width, button_height))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            button = new_button  # Both should be a pygame.Surface.

    gameDisplay.fill(background_color, rect)  # Clear the screen.
    gameDisplay.blit(button, rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

If you only want to update the area where your image is you could pass *rect* inside the update method, `pygame.display.update(rect)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are so helpful!

Comment: @StamKaly No problem :) Just one question: I've seen many people using *gameDisplay* as a variable name. Where did you learn this? Is there some tutorials you're following?

Comment: Thank you! Here's another good tutorial to follow, that I think you would benefit from checking out. There are some longish pauses since it's not actually a youtube tutorial but a recorded seminar. Still great though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0&list=PL4Yp6gRH-R1Birdm-Gs-SdBFWLUC1q3Fa&index=4

Answer (score 0):

To show changes on screen use `pygame.display.update()`.

Your code should look like this

```
width = 100
height = 50
gameDisplay.blit(button, (width, height))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            gameDisplay.blit(new_button, (width, height))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: it just draws the new button up on the old one, it doesnt replace it